# How to Use Blueprint Breadcrumbs in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, blueprint

I'm very new to vueJs and currently not able to undersatand how to use Blueprint Breadcrumbs in vueJS. I know how to use it in reactjs but don't have any idea how to use it in vueJS.

https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/breadcrumbs

Comment: You probably shouldn't. It's clear how to use Blueprint in React because they are React components. If you picked Vue, stick to its ecosystem. You can use Vue-React bridge if necessary but this shouldn't be the first choice because it comes with extra footprint and overhead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. is there any same solution for VueJS also?

Comment: Some libs have multi framework support, but Blueprint isn't afaik. Pick the one that supports Vue. If you're looking for desktop friendly UI then use desktop keyword in search. Cannot recommend a specific one.